# How to store date with timezone in database? Date VS DateTime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, date, datetime, timezone

We have RoR website. There are programs. Program duration is 30 days. If user registers before 06:00 (in user's timezone), then program starts at 06:00 of the same day. If user registers on the site after 06:00, then program starts at 06:00 of next day.
We save started_date in UTC in database. Also we save timezone name. When we need to see if program is started, we make some calculations.
The problem is that we calculate periods wrong. I think the problem is connected with timezones.

I insist on saving started_date as UTC DateTime. My collegues say that it is better to continue keeping started_date as UTC Date and just to fix bugs in code. Time is overhead, but I think that it is better to save it. Time will help us to deal with timezones.

What is better: to store date as UTC Date with timezone name or to store it as UTC DateTime with timezone name? Am I right when I'm saying, that timezone should be used only with DateTime, but not with Date?

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on this part of the question:

> What is better: to store date as UTC Date with timezone name or to store it as UTC DateTime with timezone name? Am I right when I'm saying, that timezone should be used only with DateTime, but not with Date?

A date without a time is only useful if you're referring to the *whole date*, or if you have some predetermined notion of the time context, such as the *beginning of the day*, or the *end of the day*.  The fact that it's a UTC day doesn't change this.

So if you are storing a UTC Date and a time zone, but have no other time context, then yeah - the time zone is fairly useless.  Whole dates from different time zones will overlap with each other, so you need some aspect of time in order to do any kind of conversion.

I would agree with you that you should probably store a DateTime instead of just a Date.

Then again, I haven't seen any of your code, and I don't know all of the other pieces involved.  If others on your team insist on just a Date, then try to find out *why*.  There may be a good reason, such as that there actually *is* some other time context, either assumed or recorded elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to INSIST on UTC ALWAYS. User time zone could be used at displaying, and can help to make some decision, but it should not be saved into db.

Let's review the case, suppose an user "Bob" registered at 5:50(before 6:00) in his timezone. And Bob is at UTC + 5. In users table, there is a num field `timezone` to save each user's timezone. So Bob's `timezone` is 5. Bob should start today at 6:00.

There is also another user "Joe" at the same time zone but registered at 7:00, so he should start the next day at 6:00.

```
# Bob's data
# timezone                        : 5
# registered time in timezone     : 5:50
# registered time in UTC          : 0:50
# supposed start time in timezone : 6:00
# supposed start time in UTC      : 1:00

# Joe's data
# timezone                        : 5
# registered time in timezone     : 7:00
# registered time in UTC          : 2:00
# supposed start time in timezone : 6:00 + 1.day
# supposed start time in UTC      : 1:00 + 1.day
```

Set a method to compute the start time for them

```
# User model
def start_time
  adjusted_hour = 6 - timezone
  # Always start at 6:00 despite of day
  start = created_at.change(hour: adjusted_hour) 
  start += 1.day if created_at > adjusted_hour
  start
end
```

This is just a basic idea. You need to test some edge cases if necessary.

You can either compute this start time in runtime or save it to db as an after_create callback in User model.

Then use it

```
user = User.find(name: 'Bob')
user.start_time
#A time object at today's 6:00
```

The returned time is always in UTC. Timezone only helped on computing the start time but never get saved into time object.